# Having trouble processing an int input to a boolean array

Tags: java, arrays

In my program, I'm asking the user to input multiple integers to represent the inclusion of chapters in a book like "1 0 1 0 0 1" to represent read chapters 1, 3, 6 or "1 1 1 0 1" to represent 1-3, 5. I' not sure how to process that kind of input into a boolean array and then print the statement.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhichChaptersToRead {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int chapters = -1;
        String chapterOut = " ";
        boolean[] chpSelect = new boolean[15];
        boolean rightInput = false;
        System.out.println("Enter the chapters to read: ");
        while(!rightInput){
            if(keyboard.hasNextInt()){
                chapters = keyboard.nextInt();
                if(chapters > 1 || chapters < 0){
                    System.out.println("Out of scope of the inclusion or exclusion of chapters");
                    System.out.println("Enter either 0 or 1");
                }else{
                    chapterOut = formatChapter(chapters, chpSelect);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Wrong type of input.");
                System.out.println("Enter integers 0 or 1");
            }
        }
    }

    public static String formatChapter(int chapters, boolean[] chpSelect){


    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I reimplemented your logic. Sorry, I couldn't think of an easier way to do it. There are of course, multiple ways to solve this problem.

Step one, ask for the chapters to read.

Step two replace everything that is not zero or one with nothing (that is only allow `0` and `1` - don't validate).

Step three create a `boolean[]` to store the zero and one values into `boolean[]` (which is what you asked for).

Step four keep count of how many chapters were assigned so we can use the correct plural for output.

Step five, use a `StringJoiner` to build the list of output chapters.

Like,

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the chapters to read: ");
String line = keyboard.nextLine();
line = line.replaceAll("[^01]", "");
int selectedCount = 0;
boolean[] selected = new boolean[line.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
    selected[i] = line.charAt(i) == '1';
    if (selected[i]) {
        selectedCount++;
    }
}
if (selectedCount == 0) {
    System.out.println("There are no assigned chapters.");
    return;
} else if (selectedCount == 1) {
    System.out.print("Read chapter ");
} else {
    System.out.print("Read chapters ");
}
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    if (selected[i]) {
        sj.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
    }
}
System.out.println(sj);
```

Comment: Smart implementation and solution. Very Nice!